# how to upload file from angular 2 and that file send through spring mvc on email as attachment

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

[Unable to upload file from Angular client to Spring Java server: Says 400 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847652/unable-to-upload-file-from-angular-client-to-spring-java-server-says-400-error)
http://technology.vishalsrini.com/file-upload-using-angularjs-spring-mvc-restful-service/
[How to upload file using angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39226697/how-to-upload-file-using-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below plugin to upload file on server

http://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/

And if you want to send it in email the you just need to specify that {{item}} tag to your attachment

Hope this helps